# Why aren't read-only queries executing concurrently?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, concurrency, django

I have a Django app using either sqlite or Postgres.  (I've tried both and encountered the same problem.)  Requesting a particular endpoint results in a read-only query like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59618352/django-many-to-many-best-way-to-get-elements-in-one-related-query-set-but-exclu) that takes 1.5-3 seconds before the response.

The problem occurs when Django receives simultaneous requests to this endpoint, which is common in [my application](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/178905/how-to-troubleshoot-godot-httprequest-latency).  I expect Django to process the requests in parallel and still return a response in 3-4 seconds.  Instead, I get no response for any of the queries until 9-12 seconds.  In know that Django supports concurrent requests, so I suspect this is a database issue.

What am I missing?

Comment: What Postgresql SQL string does that image translate into?  What is the execution plan for it (`EXPLAIN <your query>`, or `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) <your query>`) How many CPUs does Postgresql have?  How many disks in your disk array?  You can't expect efficient concurrent execution if you have no hardware to distribute the concurrent operations over.

Comment: How many connections does your application establish to the database? A single connection can only run a single statement at a given time. If you want to run multiple statements against the server, you have to open multiple connections.

Comment: "*so I suspect this is a database issue.*" - no it's not. It's your code. You need to use a connection pool or something similar.

Comment: Are you serving django in a way that results in it only handling a single request at a time?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.  I've been reading documentation and trying to figure out how Django handles connections.  I'm testing with the built-in server, which might not use multiple processes.  I'm going to try Gunicorn instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was using Django's built-in development server (runserver).  The problem goes away [using Gunicorn](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/).  It doesn't matter if the database backend is Sqlite or Postgres.